# snappystore - VM is exiting - shutting down distributed system

Tags: snappydata

snappystore - VM is exiting - shutting down distributed system
org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@244e619a{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}
ERROR o.a.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus - Listener SparkContextListener threw an exception
com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedSQLException: GemFireXD system shutdown.
        at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory40.java:124)
        at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Util.java:110)
        at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Util.java:122)
        at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.fabricservice.FabricServiceImpl.stopNoSync(FabricServiceImpl.java:402)
        at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.fabricservice.FabricServiceImpl.stop(FabricServiceImpl.java:374)
        at io.snappydata.util.ServiceUtils$.invokeStopFabricServer(ServiceUtils.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext$.org$apache$spark$sql$SnappyContext$$stopSnappyContext(SnappyContext.scala:1091)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext$SparkContextListener.onApplicationEnd(SnappyContext.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.postToAll(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1305)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.DistributedSystemDisconnectedException: No connection to the distributed system
        ... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Eason if you can provide some context I can get someone from SnappyData to answer